# Does google chrome beta for android support file upload with webkitdirectory attribute?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, webkit

I've been doing a lot of research on Google Chrome recently, and have gone through the beta page, but I can't find any documentation on this specific subject. I have a web app that uses the webkitdirectory method:

```
<input type="file" class="hidden-input" multiple webkitdirectory>
```

and works on desktop version of Google Chrome but not on the Android beta version. Based on what happens (more what doesn't happen) when I run the app on Android Chrome beta, I would assume this type of file upload is not supported. I just wanted some documentation so I could be sure it's not something else causing it not to work.

UPDATE: I found this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SeYgA/1/ which gives the same results as my web app. It gives you options on how to handle the action, but choosing a file browser only allows you to select a file, and even after selecting a file, it is not uploaded. (NOTE: Must be run on chrome beta for android to experience same behavior).

Comment: Chrome for Android beta doesn't even give you access to a single file on the filesystem (for security reasons). What is the directory behavior you expect?

Comment: I'm hoping for similar behavior to this: http://www.htmlfivewow.com/slide18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the answer is no.